# The boundary of a domain whose interior is diffeomorphic to the ball

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

We know that there are compact manifolds with diffeomorphic interiors but their boundaries are not homeomorphic (see the question [Manifolds with homeomorphic interiors](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95129/manifolds-with-homeomorphic-interiors)).

My question is about a very special case:

Assume $D$ is a bounded open set in $R^n$ with smooth boundary.
If $D$ is diffeomorphic to the unit ball, is $\bar D$, the closure of $D$, diffeomorphic to the closed unit ball?

Comment: The last paragraph of [this answer to another question](http://mathoverflow.net/a/81716/21095) provides a positive answer when $n > 5$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The case $n=4$ is open as far as I know.

The case $n=3$ follows since $\mathbb R^3$ is irreducible, so it contains no fake 3-disk, i.e. $\bar D$ must be the standard disk.

The case $n=5$ is equivalent to the smooth $4$-dimensional Poincare conjecture
(which is still open). Here is why:

1. Any homotopy $4$-sphere embeds smoothly into $\mathbb R^5$ (Sketch:  homology $4$-sphere bounds a contractible smooth manifold $C$ [Kervaire, "Smooth homology spheres and their fundamental groups", Theorem 3]. In our case $\partial C$ is simply-connected, so attaching a collar on the boundary one gets a contractible $5$-manifold that is simply-connected at infinity, and hence it is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^5$ by a result of Stallings).
2. Any embedding of the standard $4$-sphere into $\mathbb R^5$ bounds a standard disk, see [Smale, "Differentiable and Combinatorial Structures on Manifolds", Corollary 1.3]. What Smale actually states is that any embedded $S^{n-1}$ in $\mathbb R^n$ bounds a standard disk unless $n=4$ or $7$. This was before he proved the h-cobodorsm theorem hence he excludes $7$.

Finally, as mentioned in comments if $n>5$, then $\bar D$ is diffeomorphic to the standard disk by the h-cobordism theorem (sketch: since by assumption $D$ is simply-connected at infinity, $\partial D$ is a homotopy sphere and $\bar D$ is a contractible smooth manifold, so removing a small ball in its interior results in h-cobordism between then standard sphere and the embedded one. Proving that this is an h-cobordism involves standard excision considerations in homology).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and reference. The case $n=3$ is a classical 3-dimensional topology fact, that doesn't require the Poincaré conjecture (that is, $S^3$ is irreducible), see for ins Hatcher, Notes on Basic 3-Manifold Topology, at the very beginning.

Comment: @DanieleZuddas: Oh, indeed, I was not thinking clearly. I will edit.

Comment: Can we relax the condition that do not require D us embedded in $R^n$?

Comment: @J.GE at least, you should request that $D$ is embedded outside of a compact subset of it, and that no points of the critical subset overlap with its embedded complement.

Comment: @Igor Belegradek: Thanks a lot for your so helpful answer.

Comment: @J.GE It seems that the embedding is not so important. What really takes role is that $\bar D$ is  contractible (see Proposition A) in section 9 of Milnor's h-cobordism book).

Comment: @Entaou, I am little confused. Let$\Sigma$ be the Poincare Homology sphere. Then the double suspension is homomorphic to the sphere $S^5$. Let's consider the 'north hemisphere' of this construction, i.e. the closed cone over the suspension of $\Sigma$, denoted by $K$. Now $K$ has interior homeomophic to $\mathbb R^5$, which is contractible. However the boundary $\partial K$ is not $S^4$. So did I miss something?

Comment: @IgorBelegradek, So if there is an exotic 4-sphere. I can be smoothly embedded in $\mathbb R^5$?

Comment: @J.GE My comment is about the smooth category and $n>5$. I am not sure what happen in the continuous category. In the smooth category, assume $\bar D$ is an abstract smooth compact manifold with interior $D$ diffeomrphic to $\mathbb R^n$, as mentioned in Igor Belegradek's answer, removing a small ball $B$ with boundary $S$ in $D$, then $(\bar D\backslash B;S, \partial D)$ is an h-cobordism. It is clear that $H_*(\bar D\backslash B, \partial D)=0$, so we can apply the h-Cobordism Theorem to show that $\bar D\backslash B$ is diffeomorphic to $S\times [0,1]$ and hence $\bar D$ is contractible.

Comment: @J.GE: having an embedding is not important: compact smooth $n$-manifold whose interior is an open disk is diffeomorphic to $D^n$, if $n\neq 4,5$.

Answer (score 7):

First, your assumption imply that $\bar D$ is a compact smooth manifold with boundary a topological sphere (because is a simply connected homology sphere). So, $\bar D$ is a topological $n$-ball, by the generalized Schoenflies theorem. Now, this reduces to the smooth Schoenflies problem (still open in $\Bbb R^4$). Also, I don't know whether an exotic $(n-1)$-sphere can be smoothly embedded in $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Exotic $n$-spheres with $n>4$ cannot be smoothly embedded into $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ by the h-cobordism theorem (the sphere bounds a contractible smooth manifold, so removing a small ball in its interior results in h-cobordism between then standard sphere and the embedded one). I think the same result is true if $n=4$ but the proof must be harder, and I cannot remember it at the moment.

Comment: In the last sentence by a "result" I meant that a homotopy $4$-sphere that embeds into $\mathbb R^5$ bounds the standard ball.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek thank you for pointing out this... Actually the h-cobordism theorem doesn't hold in this dimension, I think.

Comment: What I mean is that (if memory serves) a different argument takes care of smooth Schoenflies in $\mathbb R^5$.

Comment: How do you conclude that the boundary is simply connected? Note that there are non simply connected homology spheres in $S^4$ whose complement consists of two contractible domains. (Mazur manifolds.)

Comment: @Misha: by assumption $D$ is a disk, so it is simply-connected at infinity.

Comment: Oh, yes, of course!

Comment: @IgorBelegradek If you find a reference for handling these homotopy 4-spheres in $\Bbb R^5$, please let me know.

Comment: @Daniele Zuddas and  Igor Belegradek : Thank you very much for your answer and comments. Do you mean that the only nontrivial case is $n=5$ (but not $n=4$, where $n=dim D$)? If $n=4$, then $D$ is diffeomorphic to the unit ball in $\mathbb R^4$ and $\partial \bar D$ is diffeomorphic to $S^3$. Does this imply $\bar D$ is diffeomorphic to the unit ball?

Comment: @DanieleZuddas, see my answer for $n=5$.